# Hazelcast JCache predicate

Tags: hazelcast, jcache

Previously I used Hazelcast Java API and was able to do predicate to filter on result return.

Currently, as we are moving towards portability of IMDG, I used JCache API. However, i did not manage to find anything related that will allow me to do predicate/filtering/searching on IMDG cache.

Have anyone done similar thing before?

Answer (score 2):

JCache does not have any Query API. If you used the IMap you would get the same features as in JCache plus Querying.

Comment: Otherwise you'd have to build your own kind of query with EntryProcessors which is not as convenient, but if you want to use the standard API, that'd be the way to go.